# Using If, then...fi command how to determine if user has input correct file format?

Tags: linux, shell-script

I am trying to create an extremely basic bash script that tells a user if they input the correct file format for the script before continuing. For example:

```
echo "Input .txt file here:"
read file
if $file = *.txt
    then 
    echo "File is in correct format."
    else
    echo "File is not in correct format. Please recheck your file."
    fi
```

What can be used to do this?

The command (below) does not work and just reports that the 'else' rather than do what I truly want.

```
$file = *.txt
```

Comment: That if line is entirely wrong syntax for shell.  Best to read the documentation of the language you are using, but at least use shellcheck.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below script :

```
if [ ".$(echo "$file"| cut -d. -f2)" == ".txt" ]
then
echo "File is in correct format."
else
echo "File is not in correct format. Please recheck your file."
fi
```

You can use below command if your filename has multiple `.` (dots)

```
if [ ".$(echo "$file"| awk -F. '{print $NF}')" == ".txt" ]
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly.

Comment: @ryannellie Watchout. This is wrong. The `-f2` takes the second field. A name such as "file.txt.png" will be a false positive.

Comment: @AlexisWilke How about now? Edited the answer.

Comment: @Pacifist Still not good. You need (at least) double-quotes around both the variable reference and the command substitution to avoid weird results from certain characters in the filename. [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) will point out problems like this.

Comment: Make it `[ "${file##*.}" == 'txt' ]`, then it will work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, just a file extension is not a file format. It's just text that anyone can change with a simple:

```
mv image.png word.txt
```

That being said, in this case, you can simply use the `basename` command:

```
base=`basename "$file" .txt`
if test "$base" != "$file"
then
    echo "Success!"
else
    echo "Wrong extension..."
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's back up and look at what you're trying to do. The first thing to realize is that you don't want to check whether the filename is "`*.txt`", you want to see if it *matches the pattern* "`*.txt`". Also, there are several different kinds of patterns you'll run into in unix scripting; the most common are wildcard (or "glob") patterns and regular expressions (and there are a number of versions of regex syntax). What you have here is a glob pattern.

So, you need a tool that does glob pattern matching. (Well, you could also rewrite the pattern in a different syntax, or take an entirely different approach to checking the extension; but let's stick with glob pattern matching for the moment.)

Second, you're using this in an `if` statement. The conditional in an `if` statement (the thing between `if` and `then`) is a *command* (or at least a command-like thing). The `if` statement depends on whether that command succeeds or fails. One of the most commonly used commands in `if` statements is `[`, which is a command, like this:

```
if [ "$file" = "*.txt" ]; then
```

The `[` looks like some sort of shell syntax or weird parenthesis, but it isn't, it's just a regular command (mostly equivalent to the `test` command). But it's a regular command that demands that its last argument be "`]`" (again, not really a close parenthesis, just a regular command argument), and parses the rest of its arguments as a logical expression. See `man [` for its syntax. Also, note that I double-quoted both the `"$file"` and `"*.txt"` because (as normal command arguments) the filename would be subject to word splitting and they'd both be subject wildcard expansion, which could wreak havoc with the expression syntax.

But `[` doesn't do pattern matching. It can do string and numeric (integer) comparisons, but not pattern matching. So we need to look elsewhere.

If you're using bash (or zsh or even ksh, but *not* dash or some other more basic shell), you can use `[[ ]]`. Unlike `[`, this *is* shell syntax instead of a regular command, and it's essentially a cleaned-up and upgraded replacement for `[`. And it *can* do pattern matching with the `=` operator *if* you leave the right side unquoted. That is, this will do literal string comparison:

```
if [[ "$file" = "*.txt" ]]; then
```

And this will do glob pattern patching:

```
if [[ "$file" = *.txt ]]; then
```

(Note that you don't actually need to double-quote `$file` for either of these, but I prefer to automatically double-quote variable references on the grounds that it's almost always safe to double-quote them, often unsafe to leave them unquoted, and easier to remember the exceptions where they need to be unquoted than the ones where they need to be quoted.)

So, that last command is a possible answer for you *provided* you're using a shell that supports `[[ ]]` (i.e. if you're using a bash shebang like `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, not a generic sh one).

If you're using plain `sh`, well, we have to change the rules a bit. The easiest way to do wildcard pattern matching in a generic POSIX shell is to use `case` instead of `if`. Which is fine, because wildcard pattern matching is what `case` was born to do:

```
case "$file" in
    *.txt )
        echo "File is in correct format." ;;

    * )
        "File is not in correct format. Please recheck your file." ;;
esac
```

Note that the pattern `*` (which matches anything that didn't match an earlier pattern) functions like the `else` clause in an `if` statement. Also, the syntax takes a little getting used to, with `)` between each pattern and the command(s) to execute if it matches, and `;;` at the end of each pattern's commands.

There are other options if we switch from "I want to match a glob pattern" to "I want to see if the filename ends in '.txt'". There are a couple of (POSIX-standard) ways to do this by using modifiers on the filename variable expansion. For example, `${var%pattern}` will remove a match of `pattern` from the end of the variable's value (*if* it matches). So one standard trick is to try remove ".txt" from the end of the filename, and see if it changed. If it did, the ".txt" matched; if not, it didn't. Like this:

```
if [ "$file" != "${file%.txt}" ]; then
```

Note that this uses a not-equal test (`!=`), because the strings will be different only if ".txt" was successfully removed from the end.

You could also remove up through the last "." in the filename with `${file##*.}` (and see if what's left is "txt"), but that has the problem that it'll think the filename "txt" matches. Oops.